# No Framework Waypoints - Unreliable Triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to attach "up" and "down" `waypoints` onto certain elements in a scrollable column of elements using the `No Framework` version of [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/). I'm having a degree of success, but am finding that more often than not the waypoints are triggering early (it's critical in my brief that an outcome is triggered reliably only when the element appears in the viewport).  Of course there's a reasonable to good chance that i'm implementing the code incorrectly or failing to understand something fundamental, so here's my code:

```
var scrollableContent = dom.byId('scrollable-content'); 

query('.foo').forEach(function(el){

    new Waypoint({

        element: el,
        context: scrollableContent,
        offset: 'bottom-in-view',
        handler: function(direction) {
            if(direction==='down') {
                // do something
            }
        }

    });

    new Waypoint({

        element: el,
        context: scrollableContent,
        offset: 5,
        handler: function(direction) {
            if(direction==='up') {
                // do something else
            }
        }

    });

});
```

The `scrollable-content` container has the following css:

```
height:74%;
width:100%;
overflow:scroll;
```

Two waypoints seems to work to this extent, rather than using a ternary operator on `direction` inside `handler` to set the `offset` which didn't work at all.

**EDIT:** I changed the css height of my container to a pixel value, with a Waypoint pixel value of 400.  In doing so i can see that the Waypoint trigger point is increasing (ie. getting triggered further down the page - too early), so it starts off ok the gets progressively worse.

**EDIT2:** I decided to use an alternative solution (see answer). Nothing against Waypoints, BTW - either the site i'm dealing with or my lack of understanding may have introduced 'complications' ;)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW i used the following function found on SO elsewhere:

```
isScrolledIntoView: function (el) {

    var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);

    return isVisible;

}
```